# Simple tag-only WYSIWYG HTML editor for Mac OSX?

Tags: osx, html, html-editor, wysiwyg

Is there a WYSIWYG editor for mac that allows to wrap text in desired tags via GUI?

Basically something where I can paste in some text, select paragraphs and mark them as `div` or `ul` `li` etc. "

I don't need any CSS support or auto-generated classes, just to quickly turn large body of text into very clean, simple HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first option would be Blue Griffon http://bluegriffon.org It now has a payed version but the free one is good enough for this.

You will need probably need to strip some tags that are inserted every time you enter the design mode.

Another option is https://www.seamonkey-project.org

---

But if the text is quite long or you have already "taged" in Word it is probably easier to strip the attributes of the generated html.

Sometimes this aproach is faster because in the previous programs you need to select the text to be tagged.

Using Word you can go much faster using the arrows and assigning shortcuts to the tags, for example I prepared some time ago a template to assign Ctrl+1 to header 1, Ctrl+2 to header 2 upt to trl+5 that is a normal paragraph.

Take a look at this search on this same site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=html+strip

Comment: I ended up going with Blue Griffon. It seems to be doing the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The is a free app in app in App Store named 'HelloWeb'. A very simple html builder with a view tab to see results.